# python pandas add column content based on conditionals

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to add a column at a specific index based on the content of a different column:

```
df.insert(10, 'Escalation Status', np.where(df['Reasons for escalation'] == '', 'FALSE', 'TRUE'))
```

So, when Column "Reasons for escalation" is emtpy, write "FALSE", if not, write "TRUE" in the newly created "Escalation Status" column.

My problem: The content is always "TRUE", no matter if there is anything in the "Reasons for escalation" field.

example output:

```
Country,Date,Vendor,Product Family,Case number,Reseller Name,OpeningDate,Closing Date,Case Status,Topic,Escalation Reason,Reasons for escalation
DEU,28.10.2016,VENDOR,,201610281078864,,28.10.2016,28.10.2016,closed,Software issue,TRUE,Software
DEU,28.10.2016,VENDOR,,201610281078862,,28.10.2016,28.10.2016,closed,Config help,TRUE,
```

The first row is correct (Reasons for escalation is not empty, it contains "Software"), but the second row should be "FALSE", as the Reasons for escalation is empty

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html) for compare if `NaN` values:

```
df.insert(10, 'Escalation Status', 
          np.where(df['Reasons for escalation'].isnull(), 'FALSE', 'TRUE'))
```

Comment: Glad can help you!